# smartctl questions (newbie) for Silicon Power 1TB caddy USB external HD

Tags: usb-drive, external-hdd, smartctl, sata

OS: MX Linux 19.4

USB external HDD: Silicon Power 1TB HDD (reported as ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB, size: 931.51 GiB, block size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B, rotation: 5400 rpm in Quick System Info in MX).

Problem: `GSmartControl` utility can't recognize the HDD, checked `/var/lib/smartmontools/drivedb/drivedb.h` and there's no entry for ST1000LM024.

In [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/FAQ#MyATASATAdriveisnotinthesmartctlsmartddatabase) site, in the FAQ, there are instructions to add missing drive to the db (My ATA/SATA drive is not in the smartctl/smartd database), followed the instructions to run a short test `smartctl -t short /dev/sdb`. Here's the output:

```
$ sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-16-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

When using `hdparm` command, got these output:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
    Likely used: 1
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   0   0
    heads       0   0
    sectors/track   0   0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY not likely
    Cannot perform double-word IO
    R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: pio0
```

This is the output for `$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb`

```
$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-16-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

The output for `sudo smartctl -a -T permissive /dev/sdb`

```
$ sudo smartctl -a -T permissive /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-16-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     [No Information Found]
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
Local Time is:    Sat Apr 24 21:03:53 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

Am I missing something? Why the test showed access denied in my external drive? I'm not that familiar with Linux, so thought it better to ask before doing something stupid. Can someone guide me in the right direction, please?
ps: the make of the caddy is Silicon Power, can't find the model.

Comment: I can't answer, but note that the FAQ says, "_the essential drive health monitoring/testing functionality of smartmontools does not depend upon the database_". Therefore there's something else wrong for you not to be able to self-test the drive. What's the make/model of the USB/HDD caddy? It may not support more than an absolute minimum of the command set (please [add this to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/646516/edit))

Comment: At least `0x174c:0x55aa` should be present in the database, see [smartmontools.org/ticket/237](https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/237). 
Not sure if you have the same USB adapter. Please add the output of `sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb` to the question.

Comment: thanks for your comment, added the info in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode
```

and this

```
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

means your drive isn't reacting properly to some SCSI commands.

With a drive that supports SMART properly, it should look like this:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
...
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
```

As

```
To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

suggest, you can add `-T permissive` or `-T verypermissive` to try to still get some output. Instead of starting a short test, do something like

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

to see all the SMART reports.

But SMART might just be broken for your drive.

---

[SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) is a feature of the firmware on the harddrive. If the firmware of the harddrive isn't programmed to provide this feature, then it's just not available. Using a different Linux tool to access this won't make a difference. Nor does a database table entry make a difference.

That said, sometimes USB-to-SATA bridges which are used in many USB enclosures don't allow transmission of SMART commands. The way to test this is to open the enclosure, take the harddrive out, and directly connect the harddrive via SATA to the mainboard. If SMART works with that setup, then it's the bridge chip. If it doesn't, it's the harddrive.

`smartctl` also has the `-d` option to select workarounds for a number of devices where the bridge or some other issue blocks the SMART commands. See `man smartctl`. But I wouldn't recommend to use any of those unless you are reasonably sure that your hardware matches those devices.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, one question, my HD is SATA, why it says SCSI commands? The output is too big for comment, I'll post it in my question.

Comment: Because starting with [ATAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_Packet_Interface) and continuing under SATA, the commands used for hard drives are SCSI commands. Even though the transport layer isn't SCSI.

Comment: And as `man smartctl` says, you can give multiple `-T permissive` or just one `-T verypermissive` options, but from the output so far it looks like SMART just isn't supported.

Comment: thanks for your comment, is there any other tool to test/check integrity of "not" SMART drives in Linux? What makes a drive "SMART"? The USB interface/caddy or the HD itself?

Comment: thanks so much for your clarification.